Substrate Build failures
As someone new to rust and substrate, I have noticed that besides the simple "build a blockchain" tutorial most fail during the build process. To avoid that I even tried grabbing specific tags and branches, yet they still have the same problem. I understand it is due to dependencies, is there anyway to build a project using components as they existed back when that branch was the main one. I hope this makes sense? So far the entire process of learning has been extremely stressful. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Could you provide more details, such as error logs?
Otherwise, I can't diagnose the issue.

The first thing to do here is make sure your development environment is currently set up properly. You can find details specific to your OS here: https://docs.substrate.io/install/
Next you should try to git clone the substrate-node-template and simply execute cargo r -- --dev --tmp and check if everything compiles and run. If it fails to compile, either your system wasn't setup properly or the repository has lagged behind in which case you should open an issue.
As an alternative, I would suggest you to try out pop-cli. It is a fully managed solution that helps you get started with smart contracts in ink! lang, and parachains and you have the peace of mind that everything compiles when you create a new parachain pop new parachain my-app or pop n p my-chain. This will create a parachain for you which you can then launch with zombienet or pop up. LMK if you have questions.
[ Bonus: you can use pop install to let pop setup your environment automatically but it's currently not merged to main and in a branch pop-install. You may try it out as well ]

I don't have exact errors but it happens with most tutorials. For example the kitties one. Fortunately I figured it out by using older version of rust, if I force it to use an older version it builds fine. I feel like that's a real problem with rust, either that or there should be information within tutorials that tell you to use specific version of rust and rust tools.
